# plotting aggregate data with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate

I have a data like this

```
subject<-1:208
ev<-runif(208, min=1, max=2)  
seeds<-gl(6,40,labels=c('seed1', 'seed2','seed3','seed4','seed5','seed6'),length=208)  
ngambles<-gl(2,1, labels=c('4','32'))    
trial<-rep(1:20, each= 2, length=208)  
ngambles<-rep('4','32' ,each=1, length=208)  
data<-data.frame(subject,ev,seeds,ngambles,trial)
```

the data looks like this

```
subject       ev   seeds ngambles trial
      1 1.996717 seed1        4     1
      2 1.280977 seed1       32     1
      3 1.571648 seed1        4     2
      4 1.153311 seed1       32     2
      5 1.502559 seed1        4     3
      6 1.644001 seed1       32     3
```

I plot a graph with rep as x axis and expected_value as y axis for each seed and n_gambles by this command.

```
qplot(trial,ev,data=data,
      facets=ngambles~seeds,xlab="Trial", ylab="Expected Value", geom="line")+
     opts(title = "Expected Value for Each Seed")
```

now I want to draw a new graph by aggregating ev for trial equal to 1-5, 6-10,11-15,and 16-20.    I also want to draw an error bar.

I have no clue how to do in R
maybe somebody can help me
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you `dput` your data

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by dput?

Comment: if `x` is your data add the output of `dput(x)` to your question

Comment: hi Jake Burkhead, my data is too big, when I try to add the output, it looks messy, so I edit my question and  change my data to be more simple.thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your data frame is called `df`. First, added new column ag that show to which interval original trial value will belong with function `cut()`.

```
df$ag<-cut(df$trial,c(1,6,11,16,21),right=FALSE)
```

Now there is two possibilities - first, aggregate your data using stat_.. functions of ggplot2. There is `stat_summary()` function already defined and then you should define also `stat_sum_df()` function (taken from stat_summary() help file) to calculate more than one summary value.

```
stat_sum_df <- function(fun, geom="crossbar", ...) {
     stat_summary(fun.data=fun, colour="red", geom=geom, width=0.2, ...)
 }
```

With `stat_sum_df()` and argument `"mean_cl_normal"` calculate confidence intervals to use in `geom="errorbar"` and with `stat_summary()` mean value for `geom="line"`. As x value use new column `ag`. With `scale_x_discrete()` you can get right labels for x axis.

```
ggplot(df, aes(ag,ev,group=seeds))+stat_sum_df("mean_cl_normal",geom="errorbar")+
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="line",color="red")+
  facet_grid(ngambles~seeds)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1-5","6-10","11-15","16-20"))
```

[image]

Second approach is to summarize data before plotting, for example, with function `ddply()` from library `plyr`. Also in this case you need column `ag` made in first example. And then use new data for plotting.

```
library(plyr)
df.new<-ddply(df,.(ag,seeds,ngambles),summarise,ev.m=mean(ev),
      ev.lim=qt(0.975,length(ev)-1)*sd(ev)/sqrt(length(ev)))

ggplot(df.new,aes(ag,group=seeds))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=ev.m,ymin=ev.m-ev.lim,ymax=ev.m+ev.lim))+
  geom_line(aes(y=ev.m))+
  facet_grid(ngambles~seeds)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1-5","6-10","11-15","16-20"))
```